# Value does not fall within the expected range when saving Contact

Tags: c#, uwp, contacts

I'm trying to sync the contacts in my app to the Microsoft People app. To do this, I just create an instance of the `Contact` class:

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AppContactsReadWrite);
var myContactList = await contactStore.CreateContactListAsync("My People");

var contact = new Contact
{
    FirstName = person.FirstName,
    Id = person.Id.ToString(),
    LastName = person.LastName
};
```

The `Id` property is a `Guid`. This should work fine, according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact#Examples). However, when I call `await myContactList.SaveContactAsync(contact);`, I get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

This happens whether the Id is a stringified `Guid`, "abc", "123"... anything I set it to.

If I remove the `Id` property from the `Contact`, it works as expected. Unfortunately, though, I need the Id set so I can update the contact at a later time.

Is there some sort of constraint which Microsoft fails to mention on the `Id` property?

**EDIT:** As requested, here are all 3 values at the time of the exception:

**FirstName:** Abril

**LastName:** Mendoza

**Id:** 3f451ed6-4ac0-41c1-9ab1-8aa58af2704f

Comment: Is it the correct way to create a contact though via the constructor? I'd property doc mentions AddContact method

Comment: I mean do you need to call AddContact?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis That's for the [ContactPickerUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.provider.contactpickerui#Methods).

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on `await myContactList.SaveContactAsync(contact);` (make sure the breakpoint is here and not somewhere else). When the debugger hits that point, please use the `Immediate Window` to get the values of the following properties for us. `contact.FirstName`, `contact.Id`, `contact.LastName` Please post all three of them here.

Comment: @mjwills Edited the question to include the values.

Comment: Does it work if you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.provider.contactpickerui#Windows_ApplicationModel_Contacts_Provider_ContactPickerUI_AddContact_System_String_Windows_ApplicationModel_Contacts_Contact_ to add instead?

Comment: @mjwills Hard to tell; their documentation forgot to mention how to actually *get* an instance of the `ContactPickerUI` class to work with, and the sample code to which the page links uses `ContactPicker`, not `ContactPickerUI`. However, I don't want to have to bring up a UI; I'm syncing around 400 contacts here.

Comment: I thought you do not have to provide an ID, because when you call the SaveContactAsync method, the ID field will be filled in by the system. Indicating the save was valid. So check the contact object after the SaveContactAsync to verify if the ID field went from NULL to a new GUID

Comment: @Depechie Yes, the system does automatically generate an ID. However, this means that unless I store every single ID it generates and map that to my own IDs (which is just asking for problems, IMHO), I have no way of updating the contact again later. I guess if the mapping is what I have to do, it's what I have to do though :/ .

Comment: So there is a difference in you generating the ID's an storing them for later use then taking the system generated ID's and storing them for later use? Seems odd...

Comment: @Depechie No, my IDs are coming from the database. They're never changing. Trying to keep those synced with the system-generated IDs, however, (e.g. on add, delete, edit) heightens the potential for problems.

Comment: Sounds to me this is just an extra column / field in the DB / Model. Not read the complete documentation, but guessing the ID won't change after an edit. Maybe I oversimplify but I honestly don't see the actual problem. If you change the contact name in the contact system you also need to keep that in sync with your own DB if that is in there...